# Rewriting referrer using Google Tag Manager and Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm struggling with Google Tag Manager to remove some referrals from my Analytics statistics, maybe you could help me...

**The big picture :**

I've got a website, where I added the Google Tag Manager tag. On my GTM dashboard, I added my Universal Analytics Tag, in order to track visitors on my Analytics Dashboard. This is working well : I can see my visitors on my Analytics account.

**What I want :**

On my Analytics dashboard, I have some referral I would like to not see : for instance, when a visitor is leaving the website to pay by credit card and then go back to the website. I would like to remove the payment url from the referral list on Analytics.

**What I tried :**

I was using the Referral Exclusions List which can be configured inside the Analytics Dashboard. But it's not working with GTM.

I followed [this (a bit old) tutorial](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/implement-referral-exclusions-via-gtm/) but even if the JS code is working well, it's not rewriting the referrer variable...

In order to test how GTM works, I added a fixed value to the GTM referrer variable :

[image]

And I also did a test with the {{Google Analytics Maxicours}} variable, overwriting the referrer with a fixed value

[image]

And none of those tests are working : I cannot see those values on the Analytics side.

I think I missed something, but I don't know where exactly... Did you see something wrong or could you explain it to me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I was using the Referral Exclusions List which can be configured inside the Analytics Dashboard. But it's not working with GTM."? It should be working with GTM.

Comment: I'm talking about this list : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en. It's not working on my side since I'm using GTM

Comment: this list is working independently of GTM. GTM is only sending the data to GA, then GA will apply the referral exclusion list. What make you say that it is not working? why because of GTM?

Comment: I though that using GTM was bypassing this list, that's why I was trying to find a solution with GTM. But my list is still installed on my analytics account, and I can see some referral I want to exclude on my analytics dashboard, that's why I think it's not working

Comment: Depending on your users activity, your website and all referral can take month to disappear. At least until everyone visiting your website get a new client ID.